# Firefox - enable reporting of Javascript errors

Tags: javascript, firefox

How do I make Firefox pop up something on every Javascript error? I don't want to use add-ons for this basic functionality, I don't need fancy debugging or anything, just to immediately see if there's a Javascript error and on which line it is.

I tried about:config and setting devtools.errorconsole.enabled to true, but it still won't report errors (IE and Opera do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit Ctrl-Shift-J and you'll get the error console.  That should be all you need, right?  You can see every error as it occurs in a separate window, along with its line number.

Comment: I don't want the error console being open if there's no error and I certainly don't want to have to open the console every time I start Firefox and have to close it later. Is it possible that Firefox doesn't have open console on error?

Comment: @DML I agree with you, I much prefer Chrome to Firefox for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox uses the error console to present the errors found on a web page.

To see it, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>.

Other browsers like Microsoft Internet Explorer have opted to alert the errors found by default, that is why you see them on an popup.

---

As can be read on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Error_Console) Error Console page:

> The Error Console is a tool available in most Mozilla-based applications that is used for reporting errors in the application chrome and in web pages user opens. It reports JavaScript-related errors and warnings, CSS errors and arbitrary messages from chrome code.  In Firefox, the Error Console can be opened from the tools menu or by Ctrl-Shift-J.

---

**For an immediately presentation of errors on Firefox**, for anyone willing to use add-ons:

[Console<sup>2</sup>](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/console%C2%B2/) has an option to gain focus automatically when errors are found.

[image]

---

[Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) contains three icons, one for `DocType`, other for `CSS` and other for `JS` errors, allowing you to know whenever an error occurs.

[image]

Comment: Yup, but web developer add-on is an addon, and also uses up screen realestate even when there are no errors. I just wanted simple functionality like IE has, but obviously Firefox is trying to be the dumb guy's browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is add-on that does exactly what you asked about.

See [JavaScript Errors Notifier Add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-errors/)