# Firefox - how to display JS/CSS errors on header?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon

In previous versions of Mozilla Firefox, I had a button on the toolbar that shows the JavaScript / CSS errors and warning. A click on this button - open the console, which display the page code and errors places. In the new version of Firefox (V.25), I can not get this button on the toolbar header. Who knows how to place the button on the top panel? Or maybe you know a plugin that can show the JS / CSS errors on the toolbar? Look at the screenshot, where I want to see the JS / CSS errors

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Firebug, when turned on, can give you notifications like so:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got bugged months before for the same problem i.e v25 of Mozilla. what i did was moved back to v20 which is quite easy to understand.

By the way you can use **Ctrl + Shift + J**. Always helps.

Refer this Link i think this post is in the same context.

[Firefox - enable reporting of Javascript errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166603/firefox-enable-reporting-of-javascript-errors)

Comment: Thanks, Your link helped! I added Web Developer bar and moved the buttons to main FF bar. This is what I wanted! THANKS!!!